# .htaccess how to redirect if regex doesn't match

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I do a redirect if the regex expression doesn't match

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^test/(admin)/([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})/(xml|json)$    http://localhost/username/index.php?type=$1&id=$2&format=$3  [L]
RewriteRule    ^test/(home|member)/([0-9]+)/(xml|json)$    http://localhost/username/index.php?type=$1&id=$2&format=$3  [L]
RewriteRule    ^test/.*$   http://localhost/username/error.php  [L]
```

Said if the [A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3} doesn't match I will redirect to error.php page with code id stated invalid input, RewriteRule    ^test/.*$   localhost/username/error.php  [L] this will be the error for wrong url path.

Example:

If user enter localhost/username/test/admin/TA123/xml this is valid if user enter localhost/username/admin/123/xmlll this will redirect to error.php with code say 500 input error

if user enter localhost/username/test/guest this will redirect to error.php with code say 501 wrong url

if user enter localhost/username/test/home/TA123/xml this will redirect to error.php with code say 502 input error

Comment: `Said if the [A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3} doesn't match...` Doesn't match what? Please give an example of an incoming URL to understand what the regex is supposed to match because the directory structure in your regex is really different from those in your examples.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, Yes I think I provide the example

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! ^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}$
RewriteRule .* /error.php  [L]
```

`RewriteCond` serves as guard for subsequent `RewriteRule`.

Comment: I am having this error Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: @user236501 There should be more details about error in Apache error log.